# Load another html-site as content of a bootstrap 3 popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

So wanted to create a page similar to something like a car configurator where you pick parts and in the end be able to share your result with other people.

So now I'm working on my own first little html site and encountered some problems.

Using Bootstrap 3.3.5 and jQuery 2.1.4 I created a button that contains a picture and if clicked shows my popover.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
    })
</script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-equip" 
                      data-container="body"
                      data-toggle="popover"
                      data-placement="right"
                      data-html="true"
                      data-title="My Popover Title"
                      data-content='This is the place where the popover html content is placed'
>
   <img id="PictureOnMyButton" src="images/ButtonPicture.png">
</button>
```

At this point I'm trying to implement a Bootstrap 3 accordion into that popover containing a few different panels to symbolize different categories which contain a bunch of icons on their own.

Putting everything into that data-content='' is working right now, after I figured out not to use "".

Since I added the code for the Bootstrap 3 Accordion the code blows up a lot and knowing I wanted to have a few buttons with each of them having his own popover the current file becomes really messy.

My idea was having the popover content load a separate .html file inside my source folder to make the code of my current file more readable.
Well it didn't work.

After searching Google and Stackoverflow for a few hours I found a lot of topics talking about Bootstrap popovers ajax and loading content from a external source.

Sadly all of this topics had way to specific answers for me to understand with my amount of skill which mainly consists in trying and retrying different approaches.

So hopefully someone here can find a way to make me understand how to solve this problem, I tried to be as specific as possible but if you should need additional information I will happily deliver them!